# vmhgfs-fuse permission denied issue

Tags: vmware, shared-folders

I need vmhgfs to be accessible to both root user and the www-data user.

As root, I run the `vmhgfs-fuse .host:/ /mnt/hgfs/` command in rc.local

However, the webserver is unable to read the shared folder. So I checked its permission,

```
www-data@ubuntu16:~$ ls /mnt/ -lh
ls: cannot access '/mnt/hgfs': Permission denied
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? hgfs
www-data@ubuntu16:~$
```

(The permission if /mnt is 777)

I don't know what's happening. Looks like a kernel issue. It never happened in Ubuntu 14.04, now in 16.04 and kernel `4.4.0-21-generic`, it became so.

P.S If I mount the hgfs with `www-data` account, it's then accessible by `www-data`, but not by root user.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Resolved. Use `allow_other` option to grant access

```
vmhgfs-fuse -o allow_other .host:/ /mnt/hgfs
```

Comment: This fixed my issue of nginx, running in my Alpine Linux VMware Fusion, not being able to access the mounted share at `/var/www/site` even with user:group set correctly and permissions 777

Answer (score 3):

To add to **daisy**'s answer:

If you want this change to survive a reboot put it in your `/etc/fstab` file, e.g.

`.host:/ /mnt/hgfs fuse.vmhgfs-fuse allow_other,defaults 0 0`

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying this on a macOS Big Sur (running VMware Fusion 12) or later and Ubuntu 18.x+, make sure to check out the new configuration options from `vmhgfs-fuse`:

```
vmhgfs-fuse --help
```

and set your `/etc/fstab` accordingly:

```
sudo vmhgfs-fuse -o allow_other,default_permissions,uid=1000,gid=1000 .host:/ /mnt/hgfs
```

**However for some reason**, `fstab` does not set the permissions correctly after reboots (probably overwritten by the configuration found in `/etc/systemd/system/mnt-hgfs.mount`).

So once I modified the file `/etc/systemd/system/mnt-hgfs.mount` and added the `Options` parameter in section `Mount`, everything worked fine after reboots.

```
[Unit]
Description=VMware mount for hgfs
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=umount.target
ConditionVirtualization=vmware
After=sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount

[Mount]
What=vmhgfs-fuse
Where=/mnt/hgfs
Type=fuse
Options=default_permissions,allow_other,uid=1000,gid=1000

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```